# I can log into a machine on the network via the web gui, my login and password are correct, but not SSH.

Tags: linux, ssh, lan

I can log into a machine on the network via the web gui, my login and password are correct, but not SSH. There are three of these devices and only 2 have this problem.

I'm certain I'm typing the correct password.

Heres my verbose output.

```
AmandaLindsMBP:~ mandalin$ ssh -vvv root@bOx
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to box port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2012.55
debug1: no match: dropbear_2012.55
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to box:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mandalin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from box
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: zlib,zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib,zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 1014/2048
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:3dc+LoHQi+nd2s6OYEQzf4chnSPV6Lp/EdIMwgKn7hQ
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mandalin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from box
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mandalin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/mandalin/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.5
debug1: Host 'box' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mandalin/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug2: bits set: 957/2048
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mandalin/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@box's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
root@box's password:
```

Before this... I tried to delete the RSA data... I get the same result:

```
AmandaLindsMBP:~ mandalin$ ssh root@bOx
The authenticity of host 'box (192.168.1.5)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:3dc+LoHQi+nd2s6OYEQzf4chnSPV6Lp/EdIMwgKn7hQ.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'box' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@box's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@box's password:
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the option `PermitRootLogin` in your sshd_config. You have to set this option to `yes` if you want to login as `root`.

Read `man sshd_config` to get more info.

Comment: I've already checked this, also... it's quite strange that the issue only exists on two of my remote devices, and not the third.

Comment: I should mention, this only happened after I reset the two devices I can't log into

Comment: Try to login via ssh key. There are a few options. Either your password is wrong or your web-login isn't correlated with local user's credentials.

Comment: `
MBP:ssh mandalin$ vi sshd_config

#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
`

Comment: `#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
`

Comment: `
# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes
`

Comment: `# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes`

Comment: Add logs from AUTH facility.